# Apple Watch notifications - icon not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, watchos-2

I have an app I'm developing. But when my iphone is locked and the push notification goes to the iwatch it doesn't show my app icon. Rather it shows the default app icon. I tried adding the watch app icons to the App Icon file. but it still only shows the default icon when the push notification goes to the iwatch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you put them in the AppIcon in the images.xcassets folder in the WatchKit App target?  There are 8 sizes you'll need to supply.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure all the image in the xcassets are in the correct dimension in pixels (be sure no warnings from Xcode). After change or add images in my App I removed the App from iPhone and Watch and reinstall all. Then all icons were OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AppIcon in "WatchKit" Assets.xcassets file. Then remove your old build and install new one. Now you can see app icon.

Comment: how to add the "WatchKit" Assets.xcassets file to an existing project ?, can you give me more details?

Comment: @FarisMuhammed Hope you have done with this?

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem...
All images and assets were correctly in place
I even did a clean build, deleted the watch app and reinstalled it (via Xcode debugger sequence)

But: The app icon still would not show up in the listing or glance
Note..important clue, the icon WOULD show up if I use the simulator.

Fix: After installing the latest and greatest update, REBOOT THE WATCH.
i.e. I held the side button until the Apple Icon reboots

Voila..the icon now appears correctly..go figure..